# Symfony4 - change single parameter in url after submitting form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I have a route that looks like this - route/{parameter} and I need to change the parameter after submitting a form.

I tried to use redirectToRoute but it created new URL together with some other parameters that the form passed which I don't want.

So I would love to ask you if there is some way to redirect to a new URL with the only parameter that I choose through select in the form.

Thank you very much for your responses.

**EDIT:**

I am going to share more actual information. This is how my controller for the form looks like:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->setMethod("get")
    ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            'Všechny kategorie' => 'vsechny-kategorie',
            'Automobilový průmysl' => 'automobilovy-prumysl',
            'Stavebnictví' => 'stavebnictvi',
            'Elektronika a elektrotechnika' => 'elektronika-a-elektrotechnika',
            'Gastronomie' => 'gastronomie',
            'Lesnictví' => 'lesnictvi',
            'Potravinářský průmysl' => 'potravinarsky-prumysl',
            'IT technologie' => 'it-technologie',
            'Logistika' => 'logistika',
            'Strojírenství' => 'strojirenstvi',
            'Zdravotnictví' => 'zdravotnictvi'
        ],
        'label' => 'Kategorie:'
    ])
    ->add('send', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Test'])
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();
    $category = $data['category'];

    return $this->redirectToRoute('jobs', [
        'jobs' => $pagination,
        'categoryForm' => $form->createView(),
        'category' => $category,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically change the form's endpoint _before_ the POST action or are you trying to change the redirection of the user _after_ the endpoint has processed the form?

Comment: @DylanPierce I'm making a filtration for a list. The filtration works fine but I need to write the name of the category that is used as a filter in the URL so it looks for example like this domain.com/list/category

Comment: is `$category` a string or is it an object?

Comment: It is a string.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `redirectToRoute`, but be sure to pass the parameter you're trying to dynamically set as an array:

```
// in your controller action:
return $this->redirectToRoute('post_form_route', ['parameter' => $parameter]);
```

If that's not working for you, I would double check your route definitions and make sure your route's name & expected URL parameters are passed correctly.

[Documentation on redirecting in the controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting)

Comment: The problem is that it returns URL that is longer than even all the characters available for this comment.

This is how the code I have:

    `return $this->redirectToRoute('jobs', [
            'jobs' => $pagination,
            'categoryForm' => $form->createView(),
            'category' => $category
        ]);`

Comment: Hard to tell, but I would guess that one of the URL params you're passing is a very large object, but instead is supposed to be a single attribute or a small array.

Comment: I pass the parameter category and it's in the URL as it should be but then it also passes all the info about the form as a parameter, name of the form, its children, selected value ... And that's what I'm trying to prevent (unsuccessfully yet).

Answer (score 0):

you can try that :

```
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();
    $category = $data['category'];

    return $this->redirectToRoute('route', [
         'parameter' => $form->getData()->getCategory()
     ]);

}

return $this->redirectToRoute('jobs', [
    'jobs' => $pagination,
    'categoryForm' => $form->createView(),
  ]);
```